# Cannot resolve module when importing an enum with TypeScript in a Next.js project

Tags: typescript, enums

I am working on a Next.js project with TypeScript and I'm unable to import an enum using both relative and absolute paths. When I attempt to import the enum with dot notation, TypeScript throws an error. Below is the setup and steps I've already tried. Note, importing works fine when used without dot notation and does not cause errors.

**Error Messages:**

When I use:

```
import { FileStatus } from "../../types";
```

I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../types'
```

When I try to import using the custom path defined in my tsconfig.json:

```
import { FileStatus } from "types";
```

I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'types'
```

**Enum Definition:**

The FileStatus enum is defined in src/types.ts as follows:

```
export enum FileStatus {
  PENDING = "PENDING",
  APPROVED = "APPROVED",
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

Here's the relevant part of my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    // ... other options
  },
  "include": [
    // ... included files and patterns
  ]
}
```

**Dot Notation Example**

```
updateFileRecordStatus(params.row.id, FileStatus.APPROVED);
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue currently. Still looking for a solution.